# Typescript ignores types when resolving promise

Tags: typescript

I just spent around an hour debugging a type error in my code that boiled down to this:

```
function foo(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
}
```

I'm very disappointed that Typescript didn't do its one job and detect this error. Why didn't it?

Comment: For what it's worth using `async` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: You can read more about this issue here. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22772#issuecomment-382831962

Comment: You could [augment your local defns](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsQHkzGXAOwEN0AeAMSggA9gICATBKACiIC4oiCQBKKALwA+LjxEColGnUbMWAOkUcoyAgDMIAJygBBfsJXqtUAEpQA-ACgoUAK6MIa1RAZVa9JroDaABgC6FqyK8sowRJp4JKQ6QvoiZpyUnAQQAG5aANzWlqp0mmpEAMbQMJpwALbICBAAwoQIwJq2hcBw2gDe1lApAO5QpAAqQiw0EIW2rZqcLF02mhAIcOjpnPBIaJg4eIRRLKkkthCcA3FQqXDIDEIANLNQ8wBWY8DT80SLBOac3HyCIueXU4AhhdXirMqVaqDIRZAC+lksansLXwBCgajgcBYYNgEKqEFIDU0qgA5iJ2vcIMBbJo0b1cRV8SwWPNFssINdKU8WqcKaylulsRkoLDeML4UiCCjCFBUOFseDGVCiaSoAAfOwOJwpK5QPlUml0iB9UpKiDM-nszmPZ68ylswVikVO+GWIA) if you want

Comment: I will wait to see if @YuryTarabanko posts an answer before I try one myself. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I have only pointed to the existing issue. I believe you should post an answer since you provide a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a TypeScript [design limitation (see microsoft/TypeScript#22040)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22040).    The [standard library's typing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.5/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L33) for the `Promise` constructor's construct signature is the following:

```
new <T>(executor: (
  resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, 
  reject: (reason?: any) => void
) => void): Promise<T>;
```

You can see that `resolve()`'s argument is declared to be [optional](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters), whether or not `undefined` is assignable to the type `T`.  Presumably if you want a `Promise<void>`, a `Promise<undefined>`, or a `Promise<string | undefined>`, or anything where `undefined` is a valid `T`, then that's fine, since `resolve()` is similar to `resolve(undefined)`.  But, as you noticed, if you want a `Promise<string>`, it's unfortunate that `resolve()` is accepted.

This can be addressed by tweaking the standard library typings, but unfortunately [previous attempts to fix this (see microsoft/TypeScript#22772)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22772) resulted in too many [breaking changes in existing TypeScript code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22772#issuecomment-382831962), so they didn't want to actually push such changes upstream.  Too bad.

---

Luckily, if you want to fix this in your own code, you can use [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction) to add a constructor signature overload that will take precedence.  The particular version of the constructor signature you use depends on your use case.  If you want you can always prohibit zero-argument `resolve()` and require that people write `resolve(undefined)` if that's what they want:

```
declare global { // comment out this line if not in a module
  interface PromiseConstructor {
    new <T>(executor: (
      resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, // value is not optional
      reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void
    ): Promise<T>;
  }
} // comment out this line if not in a module
```

( Note that `PromiseConstructor` is in global scope, so if your code is in a module you need to use [global augmentation with `declare global`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to get the above to work. If you're already in global scope you should leave out the `declare global` block. )

Or you can try to get more clever you can write a version of the signature that allows `resolve()` with no arguments if and only if `undefined` is assignable to `T`:

```
declare global { 
  type PossiblyOptional<F extends (a: any) => any> = F extends (...a: infer A) => infer R ?
    undefined extends A[0] ? (...a: Partial<A>) => R : F : never;

  interface PromiseConstructor {
    new <T>(executor: (
      resolve: PossiblyOptional<(value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void>,
      reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void
    ): Promise<T>;
  }
}
```

Let's use that latter type and check the behavior of some example code:

```
function foo(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); }); // error!
  // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 -----> ~~~~~~~~~
}

function bar(): Promise<string | undefined> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); }); // okay
}
```

That's better, right?  Your `foo()` implementation generates the desired error, while a similar `bar()` implementation whose return type is `Promise<string | undefined>` does not.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYQCYFcA2wcAvHAIwDccAUNdsAvgIZREDm+EARk-nAN5wA9EMQQMGYMngRc8GAAsAlqjj4lyIkoBmcZBHga4TOFjyFqcODACeYIgAUIqVEq74bAeTAwlKXgA8AGJwoDBS2KoAFEwAXMbINgCUJAB8CTbppCFhEdEAdIVxcBrawFBwAIIpxOml5XAASnAA-JZWcLjI9NoawNihIOHdqpUA2gAMALqtcFGF+cUOLL6Blak16c3xIfGaAG7lFLRWGuFQ2kwIjlDiKsAAwijoULgIMNAC7VaaAO5wAQAKqkoqAGHJoPEot8OqxUBB8Id4k4XG4PN5fP58AEovteLhgPFAXAAD5wBy3DD3AAySgA1sAgRs0nB9hAlNhUgAaGFWVgAKwYMChrCY8OQLXiTESm1Z7OwsrZHJhSWRlPuTOOVgAvtRtcJREgJFIZHJrMpVOpNCVdPpDMhjKYcARgLRtF13n4HdoIBAoqryerUIyXho2Ol+O1WDBcFAHX9A3dg1EonCEYcuXABULZYI04jgP6qNqklQRKEoLcoABCdrlgCi4CF-XIxigbFwkmkqEzXDNbAMcAmcAAtGOx+kAH7TmczvXUd3IT0oOA8KD+tVJkMwKBh0mdbrAXqaTlfPnAGNxvTAf4Urcp-MZrPAQXvXPP+EFotwEtl0QQOkmBsedqCAA)

Comment: Nice. It's there any way to tell Typescript to always use that definition, so I don't have to tediously import it in every single file?

Comment: It should only need to be in one file in your project.

Comment: Ah it works, thanks! For future people, I just put `interface PromiseConstructor { ... }` in `promise.ts` and it picks it up automatically.